# Faut-il dire « matériel » ou « hardware » en Informatique ?

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot, informatique

Ma discipline est l'informatique et je voudrais savoir si je dois utiliser « le matériel » ou « le hardware » ?
Exemple dans cette phrase :

> Les commandes concernant le matériel.

ou bien :

> Les commandes concernant le hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cela dépend largement de la personne à qui l'on s'adresse : de façon générale, plus les personnes ont une culture générale large en informatique, moins il est risqué d'utiliser les mots anglophones pour se faire comprendre. Aller à l'inverse de cette pratique comporte le risque d'être mal compris des néophytes et en plus de passer pour quelqu'un d’élitiste.

Cependant dans le cas d'une commande de *matériel informatique*, le mot *hardware* est en effet compris comme *matériel informatique*. Jamais hardware ne sera  utilisé pour du matériel pour des travaux dans le bâtiment par exemple.

Answer (score 14):

Utiliser le mot « matériel » est parfaitement adapté au sujet. On entend aussi « matériel informatique » dans le cas où le contexte du dialogue requiert une précision.

L'anglais étant très utilisé en informatique, utiliser le mot « hardware » sera très certainement compris par les interlocuteurs (mais cela reste l'utilisation d'un mot anglais dans une phrase française).